# HP 1920 - VLAN 2 issue, no internet

Tags: hp, switch, manage

I have some issue setting up my HP 1920 Managed switch with layer 3, I do not have internet on VLAN 2 or 3

What I would like to is following:
One ISP with two separated networks.

I have following equipment:
1 x Router: Apple Time capsule
1 x Managed switch: HP 1920-8g-poe+ (65w) switch

My setup is now as shown on the picture, but I do not have internet on VLAN 2 or 3:

[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKYk5.png)

Router (Apple Timecapsule) - IP: 10.0.1.1, subnet 255.255.255.0)

VLAN 1 Mangement -> 10.0.1.7 (Gets IP from router, which have  DHCP and NAT)
VLAN 2 OFFICE    -> 10.0.2.7 (interface IP, subnet 255.255.255.0)
VLAN 3 PRIVATE   -> 10.0.3.7 (interface IP, subnet 255.255.255.0)

There is created IPv4 routing on VLAN 2 to from 10.0.2.0 to 10.0.1.1 (interface 1, VLAN 1)

I can ping VLAN interface, but not the router.

Can someone tell me what I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: How is the switch configured? Provide the whole configuration in question.

Comment: After you solve the "ping the router" problem, you're going to run into another issue which is un-resolvable. As far as I know, Apple's Peter products will only NAT for their LAN subnet, and it's impossible to configure them otherwise. Since internet-bound traffic will be coming from a subnet the router doesn't know about, it will not perform NAT translation for that traffic. Solution: don't try and use consumer equipment for this. Get a real professional-grade router.

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration :

> My setup is now as shown on the picture, but I do not have internet on
> VLAN 2 or 3:
>
> ...
>
> Router (Apple Timecapsule) - IP: 10.0.1.1, subnet 255.255.255.0)

It's normal you can ping only from your VLAN1 because the interface of your router is in this vlan and it knows only this subnet.

You have two solutions :
Configure your router to know the three vlans and configure the interface between the router and your switch in trunk mode with the three vlans.

If you can't have your vlans in your router, you will must to create a subnet between your switch and your router and adding a route in your switch to access to internet and a route in your router to access on your VLAN subnets.